# Negated Turnstile?

Tags: logic, turnstile

I wonder if anyone knows how can I produce negated turnstile symbols using the `turnstile` package. The default option of `$\vdash$` and `$\nvdash$` is not ok. I want the same options the `turnstile` package provides with a negated form.

Comment: Please provide a MWE showing the issue.

Comment: Have you tried `$\not\vdash$`? I'm not sure if this what you are looking for. A MWE would greatly help.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `\not` in front of the `\vdash` for instance. However, the alignment of `\not` might not be centered. In this case use the package `centernot` with the command `\centernot`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{turnstile}
  \usepackage{centernot}
      \begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{lll}
\not\vdash &\not\sststile{A}{B}&\Gamma \not\sdtstile{\mathrm{LC}}{x,y,z,w} P\\ [1em] 
\centernot\vdash&\centernot{\sststile{A}{B}}&\Gamma \centernot{\sdtstile{\mathrm{LC}}{x,y,z,w}} P
\end{array}\]
    \end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: To get the `\vdash` and `\nvdash` , you could just load the `amssymb` package.

Answer (score 2):

Where I've seen this in print, the negation is through the vertical bar of the turnstile. So I defined a command `\nturn` that takes the turnstile as its argument and overlays a (slightly raised) `/` symbol using `\lefteqn`.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,turnstile}

\newcommand{\nturn}[1]{\lefteqn{\raisebox{.2ex}{/}}\mathbin{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[
\Gamma \nturn{\sdtstile{\mathrm{L}}{x,y}} P\quad\Gamma \nturn{\sststile{\mathrm{LPD}}{x,y}} P
\]
\end{document}
```